# android studio Cannot find JAR 'gson-2.7.jar' error

Tags: android

hi  when i open the program it show me this line of error

> "Cannot find JAR 'gson-2.7.jar' required by module
>   'gradle-dependency-management' using classpath or distribution
>   directory
>   'C:\Users\lenovo.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.4-all\9br9xq1tocpiv8o6njlyu5op1\gradle-4.4'"

Comment: you can use `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'` in your gradle section

Comment: same error nothing changed

Comment: Remove module at first.

Comment: how to remove it

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'`in your app gradle.

Comment: Try to remove above jar 'gson-2.7.jar' and add the 'implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2' after that try invalidate cache / Restart. Hope your problem rectified.